# Send array or object from php to Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to send an array of data (if it can´t be done with arrays I wouldn´t mind converting it to object) to my Elasticsearch index. I used to send my array to a database in MySQL and then load it to Elasticsearch using logstash. 
I don´t need the database anymore so I was hoping to accomplish this without it, but I couldn,t find good documentation/examples for it in PHP. Any help is apreciated.

This is how I generate the array ($values[]), it has 3 parameters $exec_time (decimal), $name (text) and $date (datetime):

```
for($i=0; $i<50;++$i){

  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  if($name == "local")
        $i = $i + 4;

  $ch = $_SESSION['cURL'];
  $time_pre = microtime(true);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $time_pro = microtime(true);
  $exec_time = $time_pro - $time_pre;

  $values[$i] = "('$exec_time', '$name', '$date')";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php), the official PHP client for Elasticsearch.
(See the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html)).

Here's another way to do it, using only curl:

```
use Curl\Curl; // composer require php-curl-class/php-curl-class

$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response = $curl->post('http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type', array(
  'exec_time' => ...
  'name' => ...
  'date' => ...
));
$curl->close();
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for.